# Ansible Synchronize does not respect delegate_to | Rsync from and to the control machine

Tags: python, deployment, ansible, rsync, ansible-2.x

I need to rsync a directory from the control machine to the control machine (source and destination are localhost). I followed the directive [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) and added a `delegate_to: localhost` to the script. Despite this, the synchronize directive tries to use the remote machine as destination and fails.

```
- name: Copy node_modules over if exists
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ node_modules_path }}"
    dest: "{{ deploy_helper.new_release_path }}/{{ deploy_app_name }}/"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  when: node_modules.stat.exists
```

Here's the output:

> fatal: [panda -> panda.herokuapp.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh
>   'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\"
>   --out-format='<>%i %n%L' \"/root/node_modules/\" \"root@panda.herokuapp.com:/home/deploy/releases/20170404121408/\"",
>   "failed": true, "msg": "\r\nrsync: mkdir
>   \"/home/deploy/releases/20170404121408/\" failed: No such file
>   or directory (2)\nrsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at
>   main.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9
>   bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol
>   data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]\n", "rc": 12}

**Ansible Version: ansible 2.2.1.0**

Clearly the Rsync command is trying to sync to the remote server instead of localhost. I can guarantee that the path `/home/deploy/releases/20170404121408/` exists on localhost but not on panda. What am I missing?

Comment: @techraf Yes I did. Here's the passage I am specifically quoting: 
```# Synchronization of two paths both on the control machine
- synchronize:
    src: some/relative/path
    dest: /some/absolute/path
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: @techraf Is the src being a relative path the issue - both src and dest are absolute paths in my case. I assumed this would not affect the behavior, but am happy to try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting the relevant passages from [the very page you referenced](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html):

> For the `synchronize` module, the “local host” is the host the synchronize task originates on, and the “destination host” is the host synchronize is connecting to.

Also:

> `mode` (default: `push`) Specify the direction of the synchronization. In push mode the localhost or delegate is the source; In pull mode the remote host in context is the source.

Comment: Still having trouble understanding this particular example on the same page:
`# Synchronization of two paths both on the control machine
- synchronize:
    src: some/relative/path
    dest: /some/absolute/path
  delegate_to: localhost`
This example does not specify mode and the comment on top says this is the syntax to do a rsync from and to the control machine. What am I missing?

Comment: This example has no meaning as it is written, it lacks the information on which host the play is running.

Comment: Does this mean I effectively cannot rsync from and to the same control machine since I don't seem to have control on the destination host? I do understand that I can rsync from and to the same remote machine.

Comment: I feel the example is quite clear in what the intended function is **Synchronization of two paths both on the control machine** - The example might be wrong, but where's the ambiguity in what it intends to do?

Comment: You can, just not in the play that is running against another target.

Comment: So ... What's an example that will work? Where the host play is NOT targeting the ansible control host. Because on the control machine you are using the inventory_hostname var to make many control to control syncs based on targeting NOT the ansible host.